# Is there a way to drop all databases in AWS athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, drop-database

There's a bunch of test databases that I have and I'd like a way to drop all of them. They all have long random strings as names, so it kind of sucks to have to go through each one and delete, especially since you can't copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP DATABASE mydatabase CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW SCHEMAS;
```

Will list all databases. See: [SHOW DATABASES - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-databases.html)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to drop all of them?

Comment: well at least now you have copy paste :)

Comment: hehe I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

In Athena homepage, navigate to the menu on the left. Go to 'Data sources' tab. Click on the name of the Data source that contains the database you want to delete. Click on the name of the database you want to delete. Click 'Delete' button on the upper right direction. Follow the prompt.